# Генератор парсеров бинарных файлов из хBNF спецификации (а-ля yacc)

Tags: парсер, wireshark, yacc

Подскажите существуют ли генераторы парсеров **бинарных** файлов, usecase которых аналогичен yacc/bison:

- подаем на вход некую спецификацию формата (в т.ч. с битовыми полями),
- добавляем код валидации элементов (проверка контрольных сумм, диапазонов значений, доп.зависимостей между элементами)
- к правилам прикрепляем нужный "код реакции", например вызов конструкторов

Прогоняем через генератор: `biton MSWordDocument.spec`

И получаем на выходе (сишный) код загрузчка/валидатора нужного формата (особенно интересны потоковые парсеры бинарных протоколов), который к тому же умеет маркировать или выбрасывать "битые" элементы, не прошедшие валидацию.

Ну или хотя бы подскажите пожалуйста правильные называния **алгоритмов бинарного парсинга** , желательно способных работать с битыми данными (что-то типа поиска с возвратами, и сдвигом окна разбора).

Применение: анализаторы протоколов, универсальный дешифратор телеметрии

PS: может есть какая-то сторонняя утилита-компилятор декодеров для wireshark, работающая по такому принципу